# Responsive layout with desktop sidebar issue

Tags: html, css

> Disclaimer: I'm not sure how to address this issue please be kind and suggest another title I'll edit

### Situation

I have a responsive design mobile / desktop with blocks:

#### Mobile

```
| block1         |
| block2         |
| clientInfos    |
| equipmentInfos |
| history        |
```

#### Desktop

```
| clientInfos    | block1  |
| equipmentInfos | block2  |
| -              | history |
```

### Problem

The thing is I dont what to setup this as a grid / table because this page as multiple states where height are heavly dynamics.

Some samples of possible renders:

```
| clientInfos    | block1  |
| clientInfos    | block2  |
| clientInfos    | history |
| clientInfos    | -       |
| clientInfos    | -       |
| equipmentInfos | -       |
```

```
| clientInfos    | block1  |
| equipmentInfos | block1  |
| -              | block1  |
| -              | block2  |
| -              | history |
```

My main issue is : `clientInfos` and `equipmentInfos` are in the middle of the list in mobile design. So, I can wrap them in a single div. But not other items.

Note, my devs are mobile first.

### Best try so far

My best try is to wrap `clientInfos` and `equipmentInfos` then use a `grid-template`:

```js
function addSpace (e) {
  e.target.append(document.createElement("br"))
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 22px;
}

/* media screen to 1px to show my issue */
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) {
 .content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "clientAndEquipment block1"
      "clientAndEquipment block2"
      "clientAndEquipment history";
  }
}

.block1 { grid-area: block1 }
.block2 { grid-area: block2 }
.clientAndEquipment {
  /* To keep the parent flow */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 22px;
  
  grid-area: clientAndEquipment
}
.history { grid-area: history }
.block { background: pink; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block1 block">BLOCK1</div>
  <div class="block2 block">BLOCK2</div>
  <div class="clientAndEquipment">
    <div class="client block" onclick="addSpace(event)">CLIENT click here to add spaces</div>
    <div class="equipment block">EQUIPMENT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="history block">HISTORY</div>
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is the case when client is to big, it result to other block expanding as 33% height each. It's not ideal.

Note: I tried to had an extra `"clientAndEquipment -"` to the `template-grid-areas` but it add an extra blank line due to `gap: 22px` which I wanna keep.

### Question

Did you see a better integration of this design according to constraints mention ?

Note: js related answers are not better imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using plain old `float` property re-ordering my div.

#### workflow

Put all div that "could" go left on top of the flow (in the `.content`).

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="clientInfo left"></div>
  <div class="equipmentInfo left"></div>
  <div class="block1 main"></div>
  <div class="block2 main"></div>
  <div class="history main"></div>
</div>
```

#### mobile

Display wrapper as `flex` then apply an `order` on each item.

```css
.wrapper { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.clientInfo { order: 3; }
.equipmentInfo { order: 4; }
.block1 { order: 1; }
.block2 { order: 2; }
.history { order: 5; }
```

#### desktop

Display wrapper as `block` then:

```css
// all media query desktop ...
.wrapper {
  --sidebar-width: 400px;
  --sidebar-gap: 22px;

  display: block;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
  margin-right: var(--sidebar-gap);
  clear: both; /* <-- set the lefties as columns */
}

.main {
  margin-left: calc(var(--sidebar-width) + var(--sidebar-gap));
}
```

And Voila!